# Adding BaseController in asp.net mvc gives Error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have a ModuleController like this. (ASP Web API Controller). (It's working Fine)

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.Http;
using AMMS.Logger.Interfaces;
using AMMS.Service.Interfaces;
using AMMS.Service.Models;

namespace AMMS.Api.Controllers
{
    public class ModuleController: ApiController
    {
        private readonly IModuleService _moduleService;

        public ModuleController(IModuleService moduleService) 
        {
            _moduleService = moduleService;
        }

        public List<AmmsModule> Get(string userId)
        {
            return _moduleService.GetModules(userId);
        } 
    }
}
```

I want to add a function which is common to all the Controllers.So i added a BaseController like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Web.Http;
using AMMS.Logger;
using AMMS.Logger.Interfaces;

namespace AMMS.Api.Controllers
{
    public class BaseController : ApiController
    {
        private readonly ILoggerService _loggerService;

        public BaseController(ILoggerService loggerService)
        {
            _loggerService = loggerService;
        }

        protected virtual bool OnError(string actionName, MethodInfo methodInfo, Exception exception)
        {
            _loggerService.LogInfo($"Exception : {exception}, MethodInfo : {methodInfo}, actionName: {actionName}");
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Then Changed My ModuleController to Inherit this BaseController

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.Http;
using AMMS.Logger.Interfaces;
using AMMS.Service.Interfaces;
using AMMS.Service.Models;

namespace AMMS.Api.Controllers
{
    public class ModuleController: BaseController
    {
        private readonly IModuleService _moduleService;
        private readonly ILoggerService _loggerService;

        public ModuleController(IModuleService moduleService, ILoggerService loggerService) : base(loggerService)
        {
            _moduleService = moduleService;
            _loggerService = loggerService;
        }

        public List<AmmsModule> Get(string userId)
        {
            return _moduleService.GetModules(userId);
        } 
    }
}
```

But After Adding the BaseController it cannot load the Modules.
When I debug, The code of ModuleController does not seem to execute. !
In the client-side I get --

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500
>   (Internal Server Error)

What can be the reason for this (just after adding a BaseController the code isn't executed at all)?

Comment: possibly because you have declared the_loggerService property in both this BaseController and ModuleController? Try changing the visibility of the_loggerService in the BaseController to internal and remove _loggerService property from the ModuleController

Comment: You shouldn't be touching _loggerService at all in your derived class, call the base class constructor instead.

Comment: Thanks, it worked ! @JohnM

Comment: changing to internal did not help :( @bolt19

Comment: See my answer below

Comment: What Resource Locator are you using? using containers like Autofac, Ninject, ... ?

Comment: Unity @IgorQuirino

Comment: Can you post your bootstrapper ?

Comment: What mvc version are you using?

Comment: **v4.5.2** @IgorQuirino

Comment: Not the .Net Framework version, but the MVC version.

Comment: See my answer below...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you registering your modules in your bootstrapper?

Try adding a class named as "Bootstrapper.cs"

```
public class Bootstrapper  
{  
    public static IUnityContainer Initialize()  
    {  
        var container = BuildUnityContainer();  
        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container));  
        return container;  
    }  

    private static IUnityContainer BuildUnityContainer()  
    {  
        var container = new UnityContainer();  

        // register all your components with the container here  
        //This is the important line to edit  
        container.RegisterType<IModuleService, YourModuleService>();
        container.RegisterType<ILoggerService, YourLoggerService>();

        RegisterTypes(container);  
        return container;  
    }  

    public static void RegisterTypes(IUnityContainer container)  
    {  

    }  
}
```

And then initialize your Bootstrapper:

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

        //Initialize bootstrapper class
        Bootstrapper.Initialize();
    }
}
```

Happy to help you!

Comment: That was it :). I forgot to add it to the RegisterType

Answer (score 2):

**BaseController**
Change `private readonly ILoggerService _loggerService;` to `protected readonly ILoggerService _loggerService;` (if you want to access it in the derived class)

**ModuleController:**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.Http;
using AMMS.Logger.Interfaces;
using AMMS.Service.Interfaces;
using AMMS.Service.Models;

namespace AMMS.Api.Controllers
{
    public class ModuleController: BaseController
    {
        private readonly IModuleService _moduleService;

        public ModuleController(IModuleService moduleService, ILoggerService loggerService) : base(loggerService)
        {
            _moduleService = moduleService;
        }

        public List<AmmsModule> Get(string userId)
        {
            return _moduleService.GetModules(userId);
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: `protected` is probably better than `internal` if you want derived classes to have access to it.

Comment: Ok I am assuming you are using visualstudio, try Build > Clean Solution, Build > Build Solution then check the error list.

Answer (score 1):

Kindly use same instance of the _loggerService in the BaseController, instead of re-declaring it.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.Http;
using AMMS.Logger.Interfaces;
using AMMS.Service.Interfaces;
using AMMS.Service.Models;

namespace AMMS.Api.Controllers
{
    public class ModuleController: BaseController
    {
        private readonly IModuleService _moduleService;

        public ModuleController(IModuleService moduleService)
        {
            _moduleService = moduleService;
        }

        public List<AmmsModule> Get(string userId)
        {
            return _moduleService.GetModules(userId);
        } 
    }
}
```

And In BaseController changed to this :

```
protected BaseController()
{
    //
}
```